# Laravel command prompt FatalErrorException "Call to a member function nullable() on null"

Tags: php, laravel

Whenever I try to migrate, I get a FatalErrorException on the given code:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('category_details', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->tinyInteger('status')->comment('0 => inactive, 1 => active');
        $table->timestamp('created_at')->nullable()->default(\DB::raw('CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'));
        $table->interger('created_by');
        $table->timestamp('updated_at')->nullable()->default(\DB::raw('CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'));
        $table->interger('updated_by');
    });
}
```

Comment: And what does the error message say?

Comment: Try `nullableTimestamps()`

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the error message mentions those `interger`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your schema is incorrect:

```
$table->interger('created_by');
$table->timestamp('updated_at')->nullable()->default(\DB::raw('CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'));
$table->interger('updated_by');
```

should be `integer` instead of `interger`:

```
$table->integer('created_by');
$table->timestamp('updated_at')->nullable()->default(\DB::raw('CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'));
$table->integer('updated_by'
```

Comment: Thankyou very much.

Comment: @wahabmemon mark that as an answer :)